# Yii magration runned half

Tags: php, yii, migration

I have migration

```
<?php

class m150218_112406_test_partnership extends CDbMigration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->addColumn('partner', 'test', 'int default 0');
        $this->addColumn('partner', 'test_pay_till', 'int default 0');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropColumn('partner', 'test', 'int default 0');
        $this->dropColumn('partner', 'test_pay_till', 'int default 0');

    }
}
```

Half of this migration:

```
$this->addColumn('partner', 'test', 'int default 0');
```

was runned, I not know how, maybe wad error on server and migration not wa runned completely.

This migratino not marked as runned and I can't rerun it because I get that firs command exist.

How to run 2 part of this migration ?

Maybe mark this migration as runned ad create new where is only 2 part ?

Comment: You could try to manually drop the `test` column and then rerun the migration, but of course it would be best if you could figure out why the migration failed in the first place.

Comment: You can migrate down to reverse the migration.